# Can an Azure Function be triggered by the creation of a DocumentDB document?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

If I have another [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-documentdb/) creating documents, based on some other event (e.g. API call).

Is there support (or will there be) to have an Azure Function run based on a new document being created?

```
using System;
public static void Run(object doc, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"doc based trigger? ... {doc}");
}
```

Binding I tried to use, i tried it with and wihout the "id" property, and type `documentDB` and `documentDBTrigger` :

```
"bindings": [
{
  "type": "documentDB",
  "name": "doc",
  "databaseName": "MyDb",
  "collectionName": "MyCollection",
  "connection": "mydb_DOCUMENTDB",
  "direction": "in"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we don't currently have a DocumentDB trigger binding. Only input and output bindings.

The underlying DocumentDB support for Azure Functions lives in the [azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) repo. Feel free to leave an issue in that repo for this feature request :)

Comment: Thanks Mathew. Yes will do ;)

Comment: I suspect the reason it hasn't already been done is that DocumentDB does not expose any sort of change event notification. I've heard talk about that possibly being added to DocumentDB but I don't think this feature is feasible. So, you might want to push on the DocumentDB side also.

Comment: Most of our triggers use efficient polling algorithms to look for new work. E.g. for Azure Qeues, we use an exponential backoff algorithm when dequeueing. So the deciding factor is whether there is an efficient way to poll Document DB for documents. Regarding eventing, yes we're talking to various teams :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-documentdb/

Another option: you can create a DocumentDB trigger that will put a message into a service bus Queue, and then, use a Service Bus binding for your Azure Function:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-service-bus/

Comment: I did read through the first link (I have it embedded in my question) but it covers pulling off a Queue `string myQueueItem`

Thanks yes, that's a good suggestion I started thinking about making use of the queue in some way, my thought was to use the trigger that produces the document to also put something on the queue.